# Rprofile.site file not loading variables

Tags: r, linux

I am on a Linux CentOS box and am attempting to use the `Rprofile.site` file to pass variables at startup to any user who initializes R on the box.  Variables are not passing and I'm looking for some help in troubleshooting.

R home:

```
-sh-4.2$ R RHOME
/usr/lib64/R
```

Contents of /usr/lib64/R/etc:

```
-sh-4.2$ pwd
/usr/lib64/R/etc
-sh-4.2$ ls -l
total 32
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  165 Mar  8  2017 javaconf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  832 Apr 13  2017 ldpaths
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7705 Apr 13  2017 Makeconf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1671 Jan 18 17:08 Renviron
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   35 Jan 18 17:10 Renviron.site
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1161 Mar  8  2017 repositories
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1203 Jan 18 17:12 Rprofile.site
```

Contents of Rprofile.site:

```
-sh-4.2$ cat Rprofile.site
local({
   variable_1 <- "variable goes here"
   variable_2 <- "variable goes here"
})
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I suggest you read up on [`?local`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/eval.html) and realize that it is not assigning variables into the global environment.

Comment: same issue if I unwrap it from `local({})`

Comment: How are you calling R?

Comment: just `R` from command line

Comment: I'm using ubuntu and it's working fine, so perhaps it something to do with centos (or your installation of R is dorked). Do you have any R-specific env vars around? For instance, `R_PROFILE` (which precludes the import of `Rprofile.site`), `R_PROFILE_USER` (which should not be affecting things here). Perhaps of use: [`?Startup`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Startup.html).

Comment: :( not that I can see.

Comment: Try `strace -o startup.log R -e 1`, then look for `Rprofile` references in the tracelog. (Perhaps `grep Rprofile startup.log` will show it looking in a different location.)

Comment: For me, this shows the following files being attempted: `/usr/lib/R/library/base/R/Rprofile`, `/usr/lib/R/etc//Rprofile.site`, `.Rprofile`, and `/home/myuser/.Rprofile`.

Comment: mine shows:
`/usr/lib64/R/library/base/R/Rprofile`
`/usr/lib64/R/etc//Rprofile.site`
`.Rprofile`
`/root/.Rprofile`
- The last two of which paths do not exist

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163442/discussion-between-r2evans-and-erik-kornet).